# WordPress Numeric Meta Ordering Out of Order

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress query that is ordered by a numeric meta value, however, the result of the query is slightly out of order.

Here is the query:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=rushmoor&meta_key=subaru_driver_best_lap&orderby=meta_value_num&order=asc');?>
```

The result of the query can be seen here:

http://www.subarurallyexperience.co.uk/rushmoor/ranking/

It is mostly in order, but there are some cases where its out of order, for example 1st and 2nd place are currently backwards (02.03.44 should be before 02.03.66).

I have tried re-writing the query a number of different ways to deal with this issue but I haven't been having any luck.

I am honestly not even certain WHY these are out of order.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's because you're using `meta_value_num` as your `orderby`.  MySQL will try to parse the values as numbers, get as far as 02.03, then hit a second decimal point, at which point it'll give up.  So the order of 02.03.44 and 02.03.66 will be arbitrary - it's only comparing 2.03 with 2.03.

If all the values in the database are of the format xx.xx.xx, you should be fine using ordering by `meta_value` instead.  You'd only have problems if (for example) you stored one time as 2.03.44 and the other as 02.03.66, in which case an alpha sort would put the 0 before the 2.

**Edit**

Just to confirm the above, [the WordPress source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2662) shows `meta_value_num` adds 0 to the meta value to treat it as numeric.  The following query in MySQL:

```
select '02.03.44' + 0, '02.03.66' + 0  from dual
```

returns 2.03 for both.